# Increase font size on vote count in question view

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

I don't like that the numbers are too small comparing them to the default trilogy sites. I suggest their sizes to be increased.

#### Default Theme

[image]

#### Gaming Theme

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - Even though the vote count is still smaller than your comparison screenshots, the CSS around the vote count and buttons has been standardised across all Network sites, such that there is no longer a discrepancy between the sites.

This happened as part of the Stack Exchange Network-wide [standardised site design rollout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/179041):

> ...there are several things that will now be standardized to follow the look and feel on Stack Overflow...
>
> Standardized items will include:
>
> - Navigation
> - Fonts
> - Buttons/Icons
> - Tags
> - Newsletter ads

Arqade's site design rollout was announced/discussed [here](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182).

Answer (score 0):

I have increased the font size, the change will be in the next deployment.

Comment: When will that be?  I asked about this a while back and nothing's different