# How is the Arqade spaceship supposed to work in the new design?

Tags: discussion, design

Previously a mouse over on the spaceship would cause it to launch the lazer weapons. But in the new design, this is no longer the case.

But I do see it launch the lazer weapons sometimes, just not sure what triggered it.

How is the Arqade spaceship supposed to work in the new design?

Comment: from what I understand, it fires once on page load now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [Catija](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/68640/catija) mentioned in an edit of [this answer](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13099),

> The ship only fires once per page load after a five second delay.

Comment: So... it's been hit with the nerf hammer? Figures.