# What happened to the alien-space-ship button?

Tags: discussion, asking, user-interface

I noticed that the ask question button is no longer on the alien space ship, but now a boring old button. Further, the ship doesn't even shoot lasers when I mouse over it.

I couldn't find anything recent/relecant on meta about it.

- Why has it been removed?
- Since when is it gone?
- Can we get the old one back?

  - If not: couldn't the ask question button be *both*? -- the regular button and the space ship linking to the /ask page.
  - If not could we at least get the cool animation back on hover?

Comment: See: [Arqade's updated site theme is ready for testing!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182) and [How is the Arqade spaceship supposed to work in the new design?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13132/28182)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Designs across the network have been receiving updates in order to be more uniform.  Non-functional design elements are only in the header and footer.  Arqade is still one of the more design heavy sites on the network.

The design was proposed over the summer (according to chat, it was around the end of August), and implemented for everyone a couple of months after that.

The Ask Question Mothership still does fire its LAZERS! but on a timer, not on mouse-over.

See the [beta announcement post](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13097/28182) for more details (H/T @Robotnik).

Comment: Ah, okay. Well, I'm not personally a fan of uniformity but that is personal preference. However, what about 3a/3b of my question? Would it be possible to enable both? Then there would be a uniform ask button AND what you could call an easter-egg on the space ship.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't go back to the old design.  The code for the mouse-over effect was custom to Arqade, and probably won't be coming back.

Comment: @bitmask It is not possible to do so. What we have is what we get, effectively.

Comment: Not a big issue, I just thought the old ship was a nice touch, is all.