# Where can I find the Arqade UFO animation?

Tags: discussion, design, mothership

I always seem to miss it :(

It's the one in the top right with the UFO and antenna and it sometimes shoots lasers.

Comment: The lasers animate once, a few seconds after you load the page. If you refresh and just watch it for a few seconds, you'll see it

Answer (score 5):

The actual gif is here: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/gaming/img/header-foreground-image03.gif?v=330ce6fa0066.

Here it is uploaded to Imgur for your viewing pleasure:

[image: ship]

It only animates once.  After that, you need to refresh the page, or navigate to another page within Arqade.

Fun fact, it use to be the "Ask Question" button, and would animate when you hovered over it each time.  But there was a site redesign that [changed it](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13132/how-is-the-arqade-spaceship-supposed-to-work-in-the-new-design) to what it is now.

[You can see the old style in this archive copy of the site from ~2017.](https://web.archive.org/web/20170207023958/https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: "It used to be the "Ask Question" button [..] but there was a site redesign that changed it to what it is now!" among all wrong re-design choices the site made, this is the one I miss the most.